# reliable way to get gas price

Tags: gas, gas-price

I've read that eth.gasPrice isn't reliable, because sometimes it suggests gas prices too low. Is there some API or something similar where I can get the current gas price? This is for an automated script, so I can't check and update gas prices manually.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A pretty good source is https://ethgasstation.info and they also provide an API in the form of

https://ethgasstation.info/json/ethgasAPI.json

Make sure to read their rules for computing the [gas price recommendation](https://ethgasstation.info/gasrecs.php) and there are multiple data sources they provide https://ethgasstation.info/json/