# What's the best way to get gas price in next block

Tags: gas-price

our wallet project is requried some update about gas price

- 1 not set gasprice by user
- 2 auto choose the best gas price

Current, I am using rpc method `eth_gasPrice` in my wallet's code to get gas price.

My boss requried me not use `eth_gasPrice` , so is there other way to get the gas price?

---

### extra request

- I AM FORBIDDEN TO USE outside api like this [reliable way to get gas price](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/44136/reliable-way-to-get-gas-price)
- I AM FORBIDDEN TO USE block history.

Comment: First, that's a lot of thing you are forbidden to do. Is there a reason ? Second, there is no such thing as "best gas price" as said in a comment of on answer.

Answer (score 0):

Just let user specify it.  Use previously specified value as default gas price for the next transaction.

Comment: If you do this, please set a maximum gas price (like 100 Gwei), to prevent users from accidentally using a way too high gas price and losing a lot of ETH on gas.

Comment: Sorry , I should write requirement first. It's a update of existed wallet project. - 1: not set gasprice by user
- 2: auto choose the best gas price

Comment: There is no such thing as best gas price.  There is always a trade-off among how much fee one pays for transaction to be included into blockchain, and how fast the transaction will actually be included.  If you cannot use block history nor external API, then you may use history of transactions you've sent.  Increase gas price for the next transaction a bit if previous transaction took too much time to be mined and decrease if time was really low.